# How to prevent the excessive usage of program-stack memory while initializing arrays?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main(){
  scanf("%d",&Testcase)
  while(Testcase--){
  int a[100000] = {0};

  /* Other statements */

  }
}
```

In the above program, for every Testcase, the program allocates 100000*sizeof(int) bytes of memory. But in codechef the maximum memory that we can use is about 10 MB. So, is there any optimal way to reduce the memory usage?

P.S. I have tried declaring it as a global variable. But the problem with that is, after every test case, the old Testcase values interferes with the new Testcase values.

Also, I have tried reinitializing the entire array with value 0, after every Testcase, using a for loop. But that takes so long, exceeding the time requirement which is 3 seconds.

The problem I'm trying to solve is http://www.codechef.com/MARCH13/problems/FIRESC

Edit: The total allowable memory limit is actually about 10 MB

Comment: What about [dynamic allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)?

Comment: If the maximum memory you can use is 64kB, then there is no way to allocate 100k ints!  Do you actually mean "the maximum **stack** memory"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth http://www.codechef.com/MARCH13/problems/FIRESC This is the problem I'm solving

Comment: The name of the site gives a hint - the stack is a limited size, it's not designed for huge data structures.

Comment: Huh?  You've just changed your question from "64kB" to "10MB".  10MB is obviously more than sufficient for 100k ints, so what's the problem?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But the site is giving back Runtime error (SEGMENTATION fault) But the program works just fine in my system, I'm sure that it's the memory issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare the array as a global variable, it will be allocated into the `.bss` section which again is not very optimal. If you wish to allocate a large section of memory, `malloc` would be the preferred way where you would allocate the memory in `heap` section.

Comment: malloc doesn't initialize the memory.. wont that create any problem

Comment: @FrodoBaggins If you wish to initialize it to `zero` always, then please use `calloc`

Comment: If the usage allows it, allocation in global static or memory is fine. (and superior, IMO). The file size of the executable will not be inflated, and `initialised with zeros` will cause the pages to be automagically be initialised by faulting-in cloned pages from /dev/zero. (on a typical unix platform with MMU)

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, theoritically if the usage allows it and if there is sufficient memory in the system, then it could be a global array. However, in an embedded system, `.bss` holds static/global variables which might be critical to execution. To facilitate good speed up, the `.bss` section is typically allocated into a memory closer to the CPU. However, if we allocate a huge array, the `.bss` section would have to be allocated into slower memory, thereby impacting the rest of the software system. A related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535250/why-is-the-bss-segment-required