# Yield 1D arrays from a 2D array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write a function which yields (in the Python generator sense ... roughly speaking) elements of a 2D array one at a time in C. Each of these elements should be a pointer to the 0th value of a 1D subarray. I'm mystified why the code below doesn't work as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void get_cords(int * coords){
    static int count = 0;
    int list[][2] = {{0,0}, {1,1}};
    // this should assign the starting address of {0,0} to coords the first time the function is called, then the address of {1,1} next time
    coords = list[count];
    count +=1;
}
void main() {
    int coords[] = {0,0};
    get_cords(coords);
    printf("%d, %d\n", coords[0], coords[1]);
    get_cords(coords);
    printf("%d, %d\n", coords[0], coords[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
0, 0
0, 0
```

Interestingly, if we assign the values individually in `get_coords`, it works as expected:

```
void get_cords(int * coords){
    static int count = 0;
    int list[][2] = {{0,0}, {1,1}};
    // this should assign the starting address of {0,0} to coords the first time the function is called, then the address of {1,1} next time
    coords[0] = list[count][0];
    coords[1] = list[count][1];
    count +=1;
}
```

Expected and actual output:

```
0, 0
1, 1
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: `coords` in `main` is not the same as `coords` in `get_cords`. The assignment `coords = list[count]` updates the local copy of `coords` in `get_cords`. It does nothing to the `coords` in `main`.

Comment: Is this a "pointers are passed by value" issue? So `coords[0] = list[count][0];` modifies the value at the address, but `coords = list[count];` modifies `coords` which was passed by value?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. And since `coords` in `main` is not declared as a pointer, it's not possible to use pass by address, so that `get_cords` could change the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing references here.

Basically this is what is happening:

In you main function, when you do:

This array is not allocated at runtime. Rather it's allocated at compile time. [1]

```
int coords[] = {0,0};
```

When you pass this array to function, you are actually passing address of it's first element.

Roughly you can say:

```
coords —-> &coords[0]
```

So when you passed `coords` to function, you actually passed it's address.

If array was stored at address `1000`, you just passed `1000`. [2]

In the function, `int *coords` stored 1000 in it.
Now `coords` in the function is some other variable which contains the address to the array.

When you do:

```
coords = list[count];
```

You change the address to which `coords` points. Now it points to the address of the `list` array. This merely changed where the copy that was created when entering the function points.

When you did this:

```
coords[0] = list[count][0];
coords[1] = list[count][1];
```

means:

```
coords[0] —-> *(coords + 0)
coords[1] —-> *(coords + 1)
```

You changed the values at the address.

Just for a sample which is close to what you were trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_cords(int ** coords){
    static int count = 0;

    // list is allocated in stack and 
    // would be popped off once func call returns if it's not static
    // static would cause it to be allocated at compile time
    // and it will stay in memory till the end of the program
    static int list[][2] = {{0,0}, {1,1}};

    // at the address that you received in arg, store the address of new arr
    *coords = list[count];

    count += 1;
}
void main() {
    int coords_arr[] = {0,0};

    int *coords = coords_arr;

    // now you are actually passing address of coords pointer
    get_cords(&coords);
    printf("%d, %d\n", coords[0], coords[1]);
    get_cords(&coords);
    printf("%d, %d\n", coords[0], coords[1]);
}
```

[1] [What does "Memory allocated at compile time" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350478/what-does-memory-allocated-at-compile-time-really-mean)

[2] [Passing an array as an argument to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Thanks very much for your thorough (and well documented) answer!