# What is the memory attribute 'p' in my linker file?

Tags: c, ld, linker-scripts

In GCC, the MEMORY command describes the location and size of blocks of memory in the target. 
The command must be used this [way](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html#SEC37).

```
MEMORY 
  {
    name [(attr)] : ORIGIN = origin, LENGTH = len
    ...
  }
```

Now, I have a linker file used by the linker (a GCC based linker for Infineon  Tricore microcontrollers, tricore-ld) defining a RAM memory section this way:

```
MEMORY 
  {
    ram       (w!xp): org = 0x70000000, len = 32k
    ...
  }
```

Could you explain what 'p' means in (w!x**p**)? What does 'p' mean in general?

Comment: What linker is that?

Comment: The linker is a GCC based linker for tricore microcontroller (tricore-ld).

Comment: I think that's important; please edit your tags.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I edited my question. I wish I could create a new tri-core tag but I need at least 1500 reputation points.

Comment: @djondal: That limit is in place because we don't want people creating random tags "just in case" or other misplaced reasons. It's far harder to clean up a bad tag than to create one, so this is a minimal barrier to entry. And in the case of "tricore", I don't think it would make a useful tag. It appears to be a rather obscure/niche product.

Comment: The Tricore manual is [here](http://www.tasking.com/support/tricore/tc_reference_guide_v2.5.pdf) but I wasn't able to divine any meaning from it. In standard GCC linker scripts, the (expression) is [allowed only for backwards-compatibility and is ignored](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC13). "P" is not allowed in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a standard linker script, not unusual for a custom micro-controller target of course.  Perhaps forked a long time ago.  It however can be easily reverse-engineered, GCC has always used the ELF format for object files.  Google "elf section attributes", out pops [this hit](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-elf-section.html), pretty helpful here.

So you got alloc, exec, write, progbits.  Aha, p == progbits.  So (w!xp) surely should be interpreted as "section is writable, not executable, initial data is stored in the executable image".

Nothing very special, that's the traditional .data section in a C program.  Compare to .bss, not p.

---

Info added by OP:

From this [presentation](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~lpy/disassembler/sp13.ppt) on the UNIX ELF Format:

- PROGBITS: This holds program contents including code, data, and debugger information.
- NOBITS: Like PROGBITS. However, it occupies no space.
- SYMTAB and DYNSYM: These hold symbol table.
- STRTAB: This is a string table, like the one used in a.out.
- REL and RELA: These hold relocation information.
- DYNAMIC and HASH: This holds information related to dynamic linking.

Comment: Could you please explain what progbits is?

Comment: Memory that's initialized from the executable image.  Like code and initialized data.  `int x = 42;` goes into a progbits section, `int x;` does not.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535250/why-is-the-bss-segment-required

Comment: If I understand correctly, this to differentiate between section containing debug related information and global data from sections containing executable code?

Comment: Hard to make sense of that comment.  You can probably get much more useful answers when edit your question and describe the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If found the following explanation : PROGBITS: This holds program contents including code, data, and debugger information.
NOBITS: Like PROGBITS. However, it occupies no space.
SYMTAB and DYNSYM: These hold symbol table. 
STRTAB: This is a string table, like the one used in a.out.
REL and RELA:  These hold relocation information.
DYNAMIC and HASH: This holds information related to dynamic linking.