# Writing my own kernel - global variables not working

Tags: c, x86, kernel, ld, osdev

I'm writing my own kernel (using multiboot2) and have followed [this tutorial](https://os.phil-opp.com/entering-longmode/) to bring it into long-mode. I am now linking with the following C code:

```
void kernel_main()
{
  *(uint64_t*) 0xb8000 = 0x2f592f412f4b2f4f;
}
```

This prints `OKAY` to the screen.

However, I now create a global variable called `VGA_buffer` that holds this memory address.

```
volatile static const void* VGA_buffer = 0xb8000;

void kernel_main()
{
  *(uint64_t*) VGA_buffer = 0x2f592f412f4b2f4f;
}
```

The code is no longer working, `OKAY` is not appearing on the screen.

How do I fix this?

I think this is because my linker script is not including the global variable data. This is what I've got:

```
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 1M;

  .boot :
  {
    *(.multiboot_header)
  }

  .text :
  {
    *(.text)
  }
}
```

I also tried adding the following with no luck:

```
...

.rodata :
{
  *(.rodata)
}

.data :
{
  *(.data)
}

.bss :
{
  *(.bss)
}
```

I'm not very familiar with custom linker scripts so I really don't know what I'm doing, and I'm not sure if this is even the problem.

Comment: `volatile static const void* VGA_buffer = 0xb8000;`...  `volatile` and `const` seem like an odd combination of modifiers.  `volatile` is typically used to indicate to the compiler that this variable will be accessed and changed by, for example, an outside process.  `const` indicates to future programmers, and compiler that this variable is not to be changed once defined.

Comment: @ryyker Haha, I just added that in as a last resort to see if it fixed my problem. I was trying to tell the compiler that the data at location `0xb8000` was volatile, not the pointer itself.

Comment: @ryyker:  `volatile static uint16_t* const VGA_buffer = 0xb8000;` would make sense for VGA memory: the pointer object is const (so the compiler can do constant propagation on `0xb8000` and optimize away any actual storage for the pointer object), while the pointed-to memory is `volatile char`.  `volatile const` would be appropriate for an MMIO register that you want to read from, but you want compile errors if you accidentally write code that would try to write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hours wasted because I was missing two characters: `-c`

When compiling my C code into `kernel.o`, I forgot to tell `gcc` that this was a compilation-only step and that no linking should be done. After adding the `-c` flag, everything worked!

And I got great hints on the way, but I never even noticed them:

- I was wondering, when compiling my C code, why I had to put in `-nostdlib` to stop standard library from being linked... because I forgot the `-c` flag.
- I was also wondering why it was complaining that some externs were not provided because it was trying to link at this step when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: If you don't specify `-o kernel.o`, you don't have this problem.  You would have gotten `a.out` instead of `kernel.o` from `gcc` without `-c`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to both link the `.data` segment and execute some initialization code for it, in order to initialize `VGA_buffer`. Meaning that you need to ensure that some manner of "CRT" (C run-time) code executes `.data` initialization. If you run some "no ABI" version of the compiler, this part might not happen at all unless you write it yourself manually.

Casting away `const` and `volatile` qualifiers invokes undefined behavior. Not sure why you added the `const` in the first place.

`volatile static void* VGA_buffer = 0xb8000;` isn't valid C. See ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues)

Pedantically, always write storage class specifier at the start of the declaration. `volatile static...` is obsolete style C. Instead, always write `static volatile...`

Comment: What do you mean by initialization code? What would this do?

Comment: @DavidCallanan Have a look at this pseudo code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535579/584518. That's essentially what the CRT does in terms of initialization, before calling main(). Without that part executed (or without .data linked), your code will still compile but no static storage duration variables will actually get initialized.

Comment: If I remember correctly, multiboot-compliant bootloaders should automatically do this initialization... but anyways I got the problem solved, see my answer, thanks for all your help