# Why do we need .bss segment?

Tags: c, linux

From Wikipedia:

> The BSS segment, also known as uninitialized data, is usually adjacent
> to the data segment. The BSS segment contains all global variables and
> static variables that are initialized to zero or do not have explicit
> initialization in source code. For instance, a variable defined as
> static int i; would be contained in the BSS segment.

I know the difference between BSS segment and DATA segment.Do a simple test:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# echo "char array[1024*1024*64] = {'A'}; int main() {return 0;}" | gcc -x c - -o data
root@ubuntu:/tmp# ls -lh data
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 65M 9月   5 15:55 data
root@ubuntu:/tmp# echo "char array[1024*1024*64]; int main() {return 0;}" | gcc -x c - -o bss
root@ubuntu:/tmp# ls -lh bss
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.0K 9月   5 15:55 bss
```

Since uninitialized data is all zero in memory, and in runtime the value is configured in heap section, why do we need it in executable?

Are all the pointers themselves stored in stack section?

Comment: In your second example, the variable `array` is not on the heap, why do you think that?

Comment: By "in exec",  I assume you mean "in the executable"  Correct

Comment: [It doesn't occupy any space in the executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725653/5267751).

Comment: @Ctx,if we use `array` to read file or configure it in runtime,it should be on the heap,I think.

Comment: BSS is not the same as heap. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

Comment: "and in runtime the value is configured in heap section" Eh? What do you mean? The heap has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne,Thanks,But I still don't understand why a executable need store a variable information,and in fact it's all zero.

Comment: It needs to store the existence of the variable, but if its initial value is zero it doesn't need to store that value.

Comment: This might be helpful: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277536)

Comment: That's because an element in BSS has known address at compile time, it resides in a place totally different from any heap allocated variable, so merging the concepts doesn't make any sense.

Comment: will data (like the BSS) is not intialized by itself, some one did the work for you , init dat/init copy. these procedures run before the glibc, is your question is not clear to me. and as said before heap have nothing to do with BSS.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne.I really don't know why executable file needs to know variables information,including global,local or static variables.If a variable is constant,we should keep its <value> in the executable.But also the variable self?Isn't that related with the code?

Comment: Thanks you @Lundin,I will read that question.

Comment: @HensonFang Because there has to be somewhere to put the variable. It has to be allocated in the executing process at the address specified in the BSS information.