# constant memory size in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu-constant-memory

In CUDA, when I delcare an array in constant memory like below

```
__device__ __constant__ float A[n];
```

does the size `n` need to be a constant?

I guess is yes, because the compiler needs to know if the size `n` exceeds the constant memory size or not. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be constant.  The reason for this is that it is a [static allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation), so the compiler needs to know the size at compile-time.

And, yes, the compiler does check the size against what is available.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the confirmation.