# static and dynamic allocation of memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I read in documentation of static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation that

> Static memory allocation refers to the process of reserving memory at compile-time before the associated program is executed, unlike dynamic-memory allocation which took place at run-time.

My question is:-

How memory can be reserved during compile-time?

Take for example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int i;
}
```

The above code is an example of `static memory allocation`.

The variable `i` will load into the memory only during run-time i.e. during the execution of the program, then how memory can be allocated to it during compile-time?

Comment: `The above code is an example of static memory allocation` Actually, no. Memory for `i` is allocated from the stack.

Comment: @FiddlingBits : Then what?

Comment: Wrong, this is dynamically (automatically, to be precise) allocated variable. Static allocation takes place here: `int i; void main(){ i=7; }`

Comment: string literals are statically allocated as well; `char* some_str = "hello, world!"` is loaded in a different part of memory than the stack and heap altogether.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: opposite is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: The stack is `static`, not `i`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits : If stack is `static` then `int i` should refer to static memory allocation

Comment: @kevingomes Sure. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Sorry.

Comment: @FiddlingBits : That means your first comment is wrong??

Comment: @kevingomes The memory for `i` is taken from static memory, but the `i` is an automatic variable, thus, memory doesn't have to persist until program completion.  It does in this case because `i` is defined in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in C can have one of three *storage durations*:

- static
- auto
- dynamic

Objects with *static* storage duration have memory allocated for them when the program starts up, and the memory won't be released until the program exits.  This is usually done by reserving space within the program image itself; IOW, the binary file of your program has a few sections reserved for constant (`.rdata` or `.rodata`) and non-constant (`.bss`) data.  That's what they mean by being reserved at *compile* time; the compiler sets aside sections within the generated binary file for data storage. These sections aren't usable until the program is loaded into memory and run, though.

Objects with *auto* storage duration have memory allocated for them at runtime when the program enters their enclosing scope and released when the program exits that scope.

Given the following code:

```
void foo( void )
{
  int x;
  for ( x = 0; x < 100; x++ )
  {
    int y = x * 2;
    ...
  }
}
```

*Logically* speaking, the space for `x` will be set aside when you enter the function `foo` and held until `foo` exits, and the space for `y` will be set aside when you enter the `for` loop and released when the loop exits.  In practice (at least on the platforms I'm familiar with), the space for both will be set aside at function entry and released at function exit, but you shouldn't assume that the space for `y` will be usable outside of the loop.

Most systems use a stack for managing objects with auto storage duration<sup>1</sup>.

Objects with *dynamic* storage duration have their memory set aside by calling the library functions `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, and that memory is held until it is explicitly released with a call to `free`:

```
void *foo( void )
{
  void *mem = malloc( SOME_MEMORY );
  ...
  return mem;
}

void bar( void )
{
  void *data = foo();
  ...
  free( data );
}
```

The variables `mem` and `bar` both have auto storage duration. `mem` only exists within `foo` and data only exists within `bar`.  However, the object they both *point to* has dynamic storage duration; it is allocated in `foo` and held until explcitly released in `bar`.

The memory pool for these objects is usually referred to as the "heap".

---

<sup>1. C was originally designed on systems that used a stack for managing runtime data, so it's a natural way to implement the behavior of `auto` variables.  However, the language definition is written in such a way to accomodate non-stack-based systems, although they'd be a pain in the ass to implement.</sup>

Comment: Have used non-stack-based system, was a pain in the ass.

Comment: `This is usually done by reserving space within the program image itself.` please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: @kevingomes: some sections within the generated binary file will be reserved for storing static data items; those data items will occupy the same memory segment as your program text (code), as opposed to the stack or heap, which are different segments in memory.  This way, those data items will exist as soon as your program is loaded into memory (even before `main` executes), and will stick around until the program is unloaded.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling this program into assembly:

```
int i = 7;
int main()
{
     return 0;
}
```

You can see that the global variable `i` resides in the "data" section and is statically allocated.

```
    .globl _i
    .data        ## data section (for explicitly initialized global/static vars)
    .align 2
_i:              ## the global variable i 
    .long   7    ## is allocated here
    .text
    .globl _main
_main:
LFB0:
    pushl   %ebp
LCFI0:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI1:
    movl    $0, %eax
    popl    %ebp
LCFI2:
    ret
LFE0:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x7c
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x5
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x88
    .byte   0x1
    .align 2
LECIE1:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .long   LFB0-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE0-LFB0
    .long L$set$2
    .byte   0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB0
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x84
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$5,LCFI2-LCFI1
    .long L$set$5
    .byte   0xc4
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x5
    .byte   0x4
    .align 2
LEFDE1:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: If I initialize as `i=7` at compile time or input the value at run time, in both the cases memory is allocated to i at run time. Is this true or not?

Comment: What you said is true

Comment: theh why first case is said to be `static memory allocation` where as the second one as `dynamic memory allocation`?

Comment: It is dynamic if you use the heap to allocate space for `i`

Comment: In your comment, `It` refers to `the second case`(input at run time)??.And how can we use heap to allocate space for `i`?

Comment: `int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int));` will allocate heap space dynamically for an `int`

Comment: I want to know `void main() { int i ; }` is `static memory allocation` or not. `i` in this case is not a pointer, just an `int`

Comment: In your case, `i` is allocated from the stack at runtime.

Comment: That I know, but whether it is static memory allocation or dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: I would say neither.  It is automatically allocated on the stack.

Comment: and what about int i=7;. Is it static,dynamic or automatically allocated

Comment: It all depends on where that statement is.  If it is inside of a function, then neither.  If it is outside function, then it is static.  It is dynamic when you use `malloc` or some variant.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling your code, the compiler decides how much memory to assign to each object (say variable or code of function), in which order they will be placed in memory and at what addresses. Of course variables might not get created until the program is started, but the memory is allocated in advance, the variable addresss is already compiled into the code - for example the `i` variable address is compiled into the  `i=7;` instruction.

**EDIT**

Variables may be allocated statically or dynamically, and dynamic variables may be allocated automatically (in C/C++ they are usually local variables in functions, created on a stack or in registers) or 'manually', that is in controllable manner (created by `malloc` or `new` and disposed by `free` or `delete`). Static variables exist through the whole process life time, dynamic variables are created when needed and destroyed after use.

```
int fun( int param)
{
    int automatic_var = 3;
    return automatic_var + ++param;
}

int static_var = 7;

void main()
{
    int automatic_var2;
    automatic_var2 = fun( static_var);
}
```

In the code above, `automatic_var2` gets assigned value `11`.
Variable `static_var` existsts through the whole process execution time,
variable `automatic_var2` exists during the `main()` execution time,
variable `automatic_var` and `param` exist only during the `fun()` execution time.

Sometimes, automatic allocation is considered a third way, separate from <del>automatic</del> dynamic allocation. Anyway, the `int i;` declaration inside a function, whether considered dynamic or not, certainly is **not** a *static* allocation (even if it is `main()`, whose execution time covers *almost* the whole proces execution time).

Comment: `but the memory is allocated in advance`.so does it do not occur in case of dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Opposite is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation

Answer (score 0):

In C there are four forms of storage:

- automatic (aka. stack)
- thread
- static
- allocated (aka. heap)

Some authors divide these up into two categories, static and dynamic . Everyone agrees that *static* is static, and *allocated* is dynamic, but your example is *automatic*, so assigning it to one of the other categories is rather arbitrary.  It seems clearer to me to just use the standard terms.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of static and dynamic memory allocation, your program gets memory only when it is executing.

While executing there comes the concept of static and dynamic. When executing a static memory is allocated in one of data or code segment. Dynamic allocation happens when u call malloc or calloc which gets memory in heap and this happens only when the statement containing malloc or calloc happens and they are called dynamic.

It is not like after compiling the memory is allocated on ur RAM. 
In C static and dynamic concept comes only when the program is executing, else there is no memory allocated to your code.