# Difference in object definition with and without "new"

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I found two ways of object definition.

> Demo d;
>
> Demo *ptrD = new Demo();

Is there any difference between above two object definition in cpp

where Demo is a class

```
 class Demo 
    {
         // --------------
         //---------------
    };
```

Is there any difference in memory allocated to object created by these two statements?

Comment: It should be Demo *ptrd = new Demo();

Comment: `new` allocates memory dynamically, while the first example does it statically. The rest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: @Sumeet No, it shouldn't. There is no -need- to do this. Some people find this a good practice, but i personally disagree with that.

Comment: @Nallath: The guy has written Demo d = new Demo();, during initial post. I posted so that he can correct it.

Comment: The `()` in `new Demo()`  is an *initializer*, which in general case also creates extra differences between these two variants. If you want to restrict the question to matters of storage and lifetime, it would be a good idea to eliminate that difference first. Either `Demo d;` vs. `new Demo` or `Demo d{}` vs `new Demo{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course.
the first one is an object created and allocated from the stack. it will be deleted automatically when its scope is over.
that has being said:

1. you can't return it as pointer or reference - because then you'll return a memory address which does not point to a valid object
2. if you return it, it will return as copy or move
3. you don't have to be afraid of memory leaks, becuase it's de-allocated automatically
4. allocating it is much faster then the alternative heap allocation

the second one is allocated from the heap. a heap is a huge memory block given to you by the OS. that has being said:

- an object allocated with new will live on untill you call `delete` on it
- it's scope is universal to the program
- you must pass it as a pointer or reference (well, you should, anyway)
- you must `delete` it on some point
- heap allocation is slower
- the dangers of memory leak is greater

there are many many other neuanses to these, including polimorphism, multi-threaded enviroments and much more.
learn about memory managment, know it as the palm of you hand , but opt `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` when time comes by.

Answer (score 1):

For `Demo d;` `d` will be allocated on stack and automatically freed when the program leaves the current block.

For `Demo *d = new Demo();` `d` is a pointer to an object allocated on heap. Such objects remain in existence until explicitly freed with `delete` operator: `delete d`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that writing `Demo d;` causes the object instance to be created and destroyed automatically (also known as [RAII](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)), whereas in the second case you have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

In first case:

```
Demo d;
```

The object will get allocated on the stack and is automatically deleted once the scope of the declaration is left.

In second case:

```
Demo *d = new Demo();
```

The object will get allocated over free store/heap. You need to explicitly delete object by calling `delete` operator.