# Difference between lifetimes of variables created on stack and heap?

Tags: c

i know that heap is used in case of dynamic memory allocation otherwise stack is used.
i have tried [Difference between static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)
i know the difference but confusion is about their lifetimes.

Comment: What kind of confusion?

Comment: they are all dead when the program terminates

Comment: Stack variables live until their scope ends (the closing `}` is reached from the point where they are declared). Dynamic variables live until you call `free` or `realloc` on them. That's about it - nothing else to understand.

Comment: what if we do not free the memory?  @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @SakshiRajput Then you have a memory leak until your program exits, at which point the memory is freed by the execution environment.

Comment: @ericbn Err... no. You should actually read the question before suggesting duplicates.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight With all due respect -- *objects* are on the stack or heap, variables aren't. Variables have scope, objects have lifetime.

Comment: @SakshiRajput If you do not free, the run time environment is in charge. Part of it is the C runtime library (which comes with the compiler), part is the operating system. Modern and common run times -- gcc on Linux, VS on Windows -- return the aplication's heap to the OS when an executable ends. Simpler run times may fail to do that so that your machine has less memory available. But note that no destructors will be called on heap objects if you don't free them which may be bad if they hold resources the OS doesn't know about.

Comment: Contd...  For example, files will be closed at program exit, but database connections probably not.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer of the linked question [Difference between static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation) is wrong because it confuses static and automatic storage.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Please dont compare stack with dynamic. this are 2 complete different principles. stack vs. heap is an design concept. And has in Theory nothing to do with the kind of storage duration chosen. Where there are 3 in plain C and afaik 4 in c++. so there are in c: static storage types, automatic stoare types (what you probably meant by stack variables) and allocated storage types. (which is in c++ named dynamic afaik). But please keep the names of theese topics seperated from each other. as they are 2 completly different things, albeit theese things are related.

Comment: John is the only one who got it right. There is a third static storage duration called "static". They last as long as the program and are associated with (file) global or static variables.

Comment: @Zaibis Please don't confuse comments with answers.

Comment: @Zaibis As much as I am for exactness -- can you provide an example in C -- i.e. an implemenation --  where allocated objects are not on the heap and objects with automatic storage duration are not on the stack? If not, the terms are interchangeable for all ends and purposes.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Well I can't provide a concret example, but I could imagine cases where some optimizations detect that an object is allocated and freed in the same scope without beeing accessable outside of the scope what could make the compiler decide to not even allocate it at all and just put it on the stack. But at all this doesn't matter. I aggree that the concept of heap and stack works this way, BUT the concept is not part of the language. so one can't claim that "it works this way in C" since this is not mentioned by the c draft in any way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yeah, thats ok, but anyway it wouldn't hurt to not mix up this words. I simply wanted to clarify.

Comment: Thank you all. This was really helpful. It has cleared many of my concepts.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, stacks and heaps are implementation details (the words "stack" and "heap" do not appear anywhere in the [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).  Instead, the standard talks about *storage durations* for objects (Section 6.2.4).

As of C2011, there are four storage durations: *static*, *automatic*, *thread*, and *allocated*.

Objects with static storage duration have lifetimes<sup>1</sup> that extend over the lifetime of the program.  That is, memory is set aside for them when the program is loaded, and that memory is released when the program exits.  Objects declared at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword have static storage duration.  Storage for static objects is usually allocated from within the binary image itself (for ELF, this would include the `.data`, `.rodata`, and `.bss` sections); that is, something other than a stack or heap.

Objects with automatic storage duration have lifetimes that extend from the entry of the block in which they're created until the block exits<sup>2</sup>.    If the block is entered recursively, a new object is created.  Objects declared within a block without the `static` keyword have automatic storage duration.  Objects with automatic storage duration are *usually* allocated from a runtime hardware stack, although not all architectures have a stack.

Objects with thread storage duration have lifetimes that extend over the execution of the thread for which they were created.  Objects declared with the `_Thread_local` keyword have thread storage duration.  I *think* thread-local objects are allocated in the same way as auto variables, but that may be wrong; I've never used C2011 native threading, so I can't say for sure.

Objects with allocated storage duration have lifetimes that extend from the time they are allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` until they are explicitly deallocated with a call to `free`.  Objects with allocated storage duration are usually allocated from the heap (although not all architectures will have a heap as such).  Where things get confusing is distinguishing the allocated object from the object that points to it.  Given the following code:

```
int *foo( void )
{
  int *bar = malloc( sizeof *bar * 10 );
  // do stuff with bar
  return bar;
}

void bletch( void )
{
  int *blurga = foo();
  // do stuff with blurga
  free( blurga );
}
```

We've allocated *three* objects.  In the function `foo`, we allocate a pointer object (referred to by the variable `bar`) with automatic storage duration; its lifetime is the lifetime of the function `foo`.  In the function `bletch`, we allocate another pointer object (referred to by the variable `blurga`) with automatic storage duration; its lifetime extends over the lifetime of the function `bletch`.

The third object is a buffer large enough to hold 10 `int` objects.  Its lifetime extends from the `malloc` call in `foo` to the `free` call in `bletch`; its lifetime is not tied to the lifetime of any function or block.

---

1. The lifetime of an object is the time within a program's execution that storage is guaranteed to be reserved for that object.  Note that the *lifetime* of an object is distinct from the *scope* of the identifier that refers to that object.  Even though memory for the object may be allocated at block entry, the scope of the identifier that refers to it may be more limited.
Assume the following code:

```
void foo()
{
  printf( "entered foo\n" );
  int i = 0;
  while ( i < 10 )
    printf( "%d\n", i++ );
}
```

The *scope* of the variable `i` extends from the end of its declaration until the end of the block; however, the *lifetime* of the integer object `i` refers to extends from block entry until block exit.

2. In practice, most compilers will set aside storage for all block-scope variables at function entry, even though some may be local to a block within the function.  However, it's best to assume that the lifetime of an `auto` object only extends to the block in which it is contained.

Comment: Nice answer. For your suggestion that allocation for thread local would be similar to `auto`, no I don't think that one can say that, it is really something apart. They use memory that is set aside when the thread starts up and deleted when it ends.

Comment: @JensGustedt: yeah, I've never played with `_Thread_local` objects, so I'm not sure how they're usually allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Stack variables have local scope, meaning they are only valid to de-reference within the pair of `{}` where they were declared. While a dynamically allocated variable is valid until the point where your program calls `free()`.

A more correct name would be local variables, since local variables may also end up allocated in CPU registers and not always on the stack. Formally, they are called variables with *automatic storage duration* in the C standard, meaning that the compiler automatically decides which is the best place to allocate them at.

Comment: Hm. I did not know you could allocate variables. You can allocate memory or perhaps even objects though (although I would argue that you *create* objects, which is the two-stage process of providing memory and running a constructor).

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks for the off-topic, non-constructive rant. I felt it really contributed something of great value to the site.

Comment: Sorry if my comment made the impression of a rant. It was meant to be sincere, sober, constructive and on-topic. It is important to be exact when talking about lifetime/storage duration and scope. I just searched the standard (n1570 draft) for "variable". There is no formal definition of it. The word is rarely used in the sense of name+value, and then often in remarks. (It's used more often as an adjective for variable length arrays and argument lists). Wikipedia (I know) seems to say "name and changeable value". One certainly does not allocate the name, so that ... [to be ctd.]

Comment: [...ctd] "allocated variable" seems a bit fuzzy to me. It seems clearer to distinguish between the identifier which has a scope and does not need allocation, and the memory/storage that holds the associated value, which does need allocation and has a "duration" or life time. No rant intended. I usually appreciate your contributions, of course.

Comment: @PeterSchneider This answer was meant to address a programming beginner, not the C standard committee. Search the C standard for the definition of "pedagogy" and you will find that it isn't mentioned there either.

Comment: The point was, it was not helpful for the beginner. Consider `{ int*p = malloc(sizeof(int)); }`. We have an identifier p with local scope, the value of p with automatic storage duration, and a memory location with dynamic storage duration which does not have a name. `p`  is actually a "stack variable with local scope", but I bet you the OP has problems to get their head around all that. He would probably say "p is a dynamically allocated variable". Hey, there was a malloc!