# Free (deleting) allocated memory from the function readdir

Tags: c, linux, stack, malloc, free

I am using the C programming language in the Linux environment to read the files in a directory. I have include `#include<dirent.h>` in my code and am using the function `readdir()`.

According to the Linux page online it says not to call `free()` on the resulting pointer to a `dirent` structure because it may be allocated on the stack.

Can you help me understand how that works? I don't understand why we would not have to delete the `struct dirent`. When is it deleted and who deletes it?

[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) is the excerpt I am talking about:

> On success, `readdir()` returns a pointer to a `dirent` structure. (This structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to `free(3)` it.) If the end of the directory stream is reached, `NULL` is returned and `errno` is not changed. If an error occurs, `NULL` is returned and `errno` is set appropriately.

Comment: Because that is a pointer to a `static` variable within the function, it is not yours to free. The clue is that the data gets overwritten on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 13):

`man readdir` literally says:

> On  success,  `readdir()` returns a pointer to a dirent structure. 
>   (This structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to 
>   `free(3)` it.)

<sub>(Code formatters added.)</sub>

That means the space for it is not allocated at runtime such as stack or free store memory but is `static`: it is in the executable itsself, comparable to string literals with the difference that writing to string literals is undefined behavior.

Imagine the implementation to be something like this:

```
struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp) {
    static struct dirent dir;

    /* Fill dir with appropriate values. */

    return &dir;
}
```

`dir` is statically allocated here. Returning its address isn't wrong because it exists throughout the whole runtime of the program.

Here is the actual source code of `readdir` on my glibc 2.22 implementation (the path is `/sysdeps/posix/readdir.c`):

```
DIRENT_TYPE *
__READDIR (DIR *dirp)
{
  DIRENT_TYPE *dp;
  int saved_errno = errno;

#if IS_IN (libc)
  __libc_lock_lock (dirp->lock);
#endif

  do
    {
      size_t reclen;

      if (dirp->offset >= dirp->size)
    {
      /* We've emptied out our buffer.  Refill it.  */

      size_t maxread;
      ssize_t bytes;

#ifndef _DIRENT_HAVE_D_RECLEN
      /* Fixed-size struct; must read one at a time (see below).  */
      maxread = sizeof *dp;
#else
      maxread = dirp->allocation;
#endif

      bytes = __GETDENTS (dirp->fd, dirp->data, maxread);
      if (bytes <= 0)
        {
          /* On some systems getdents fails with ENOENT when the
         open directory has been rmdir'd already.  POSIX.1
         requires that we treat this condition like normal EOF.  */
          if (bytes < 0 && errno == ENOENT)
        bytes = 0;

          /* Don't modifiy errno when reaching EOF.  */
          if (bytes == 0)
        __set_errno (saved_errno);
          dp = NULL;
          break;
        }
      dirp->size = (size_t) bytes;

      /* Reset the offset into the buffer.  */
      dirp->offset = 0;
    }

      dp = (DIRENT_TYPE *) &dirp->data[dirp->offset];

#ifdef _DIRENT_HAVE_D_RECLEN
      reclen = dp->d_reclen;
#else
      /* The only version of `struct dirent*' that lacks `d_reclen'
     is fixed-size.  */
      assert (sizeof dp->d_name > 1);
      reclen = sizeof *dp;
      /* The name is not terminated if it is the largest possible size.
     Clobber the following byte to ensure proper null termination.  We
     read jst one entry at a time above so we know that byte will not
     be used later.  */
      dp->d_name[sizeof dp->d_name] = '\0';
#endif

      dirp->offset += reclen;

#ifdef _DIRENT_HAVE_D_OFF
      dirp->filepos = dp->d_off;
#else
      dirp->filepos += reclen;
#endif

      /* Skip deleted files.  */
    } while (dp->d_ino == 0);

#if IS_IN (libc)
  __libc_lock_unlock (dirp->lock);
#endif

  return dp;
}
```

I don't know much about glibc but the line

```
dp = (DIRENT_TYPE *) &dirp->data[dirp->offset];
```

seems the most interesting to us. `dirp->data` is the `static` data here, as far as I can tell.

---

That is the reason as to why there is the reentrant alternative `readdir_r` and `readdir` is **not reentrant**.
Imagine two threads concurrently executing `readdir`. Both will attempt to fill `dir`, which is shared among all `readdir` invocations, simultaneously, resulting in unsequenced memory reads/writes.

Answer (score 4):

The *[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir)* you reference is cautioning that the `struct dirent` is *[statically allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793111/645128)*.  Therefore `free()`is not necessary.

*[free()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)* is designed exclusively for use with  *[[m][c][re]alloc()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)* functions, which all make requests for memory from the *[heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80113/645128)*. (as opposed to the stack)

Answer (score 2):

The `struct dirent` is logically part of the `DIR`. It may be reused in a subsequent `readdir()` call on the same `DIR` (but not in a `readdir()` call on a different `DIR`) and will be freed upon `closedir()`.

Some documentation states that `readdir()` is not thread-safe. In all implementations except really exotic ones, it is thread-safe as long as the last access to the previous `struct dirent` happens-before the next `readdir()` call. Using `readdir_r()` is not advisable because it is very hard to determine the NAME_MAX limit properly and the `readdir_r()` function does not know the value used by its caller.

More details about the problems with `readdir_r()` are at http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=696.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to `free()` the memory which has been previously allocated by a call to `malloc()` and family. This is [dynamically allocated memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), from *heap* area.

OTOH, non-dynamic allocation (see [automatic allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)) need not to be *handled* separately. Once the variable goes out of scope, the stack memory is reclaimed and reused as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to free/release entries fetched by `readdir()`. It uses a static internal buffer and thus it does not need to be freed dynamically because it's not allocated dynamically. Note that the compiler can predict the space needed because you only use one entry at a time and you just need one entry to store the results. This is why it's not reentrant too. There is a [`readdir_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) which takes a user allocated buffer and is of course reentrant.

You need to call `closedir()` on the `DIR *` pointer in order to free the resources used by `opendir()`.