# Char string in a struct C

Tags: c, string, struct

I need your help!
Why in C structures of data that stores in char strings **works only 1 type of declaration**: `char *name;` works, but `char []name;` does not work.

But when to try declare a char string inside the code (without using struct), **everything works**. Code example that illustrate, what when to declare char array, both of the declaration types works.

```
#include "funct.h"
#include "stdio.h"

//structure employee name and surname only works when using char* pointers

struct employee {
    char *name;
    char *surname;
};

int main() {
    struct employee worker;
    worker.name = "Robert";
    worker.surname = "Woz";

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", worker.name);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", worker.surname);
    printf("\n");

    char name[] = "Robert";   //declaration of array with using [] postfix

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%c", name[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    char *surname = "Woz";   //declaration of array wit using char* pointer

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%c", surname[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Program output:

```
Robert
Woz
Robert
Woz
```

Comment: C or C++? Choose one.

Comment: `char *surname` doesn't declare an array; it declares a pointer.

Comment: `char *surname="Woz";` creates a string literal of static lifetime and assigns `surname` to point at it. `char name[]="Robert";` creates a character array of scoped lifetime, an array is _not the same as a pointer_ , and so an array has some extra information i.e. it's size, where as a pointer won't know how much memory it's pointing at.

Comment: `char []name` -> should be `char name[size]`

Comment: so `char *surname="Woz";` creates pointer for first char element of array surname, but whene is determined size of memory that store surname?

Comment: `char name[] = "Robert";`  works, but `char name[]; name = "Robert";` won't. The latter is what you try, with the only difference that you try to wrap it inside a `struct`.

Comment: @tuple_cat yea that is when he doesn't have the intended size in mind. and it should be unsigned char[]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to include the standard library headers use `<header.h>` instead of `"header.h"`. When using the quotes the compiler will atempt to find the header in the file directory. When using `<>` the compiler looks for the header in your include directory.

Secondly, the declaration using brackets accepts only `char name[];`, not `char []name;`. But if you declare this way in a structure, you need to specify the size, like `char name[30];`. You can only declare without a size when declaring a single variable and initializing it with a string literal, so the compiler will deduce the size from the string literal. Example: `char name[] = "Robert";`.

Thirdly, the difference of declaring `char* name` from declaring `char name[30]` is that in the first way you declare a pointer to a sequence of chars in the memory, while in the second way, you declare a fixed size array. Note that assigning a fixed size array to a smaller string literal (or bigger) after its initializing may result in an error, while assigning a `char` pointer will allow you assinging it to any size string literal.

Comment: But size of array that declared in this way `char* name` will be static, or i can redeclare it by using `realloc();` function?

Comment: `char* name` does not define an array at all, but just a pointer that ***could*** point to an a `char`, which ***could*** be the 1st element of an array, ***if*** you made it point to it.

Comment: For using `realloc` on anything, you first need to use `malloc` or `calloc` and assigns `malloc` return value to it. And after using the variable which you assigned to `malloc`, you need to use `free` on it. If you intend to use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc` family, then use a `char*`. If you intend to reassign the variable to different sized string literals, you should also use `char*`.

Comment: So `char *surname="Woz";` is equivalent (in way, that will be created the similar static arrays with 4 elements) `char surname[4]="Woz";`?

Comment: It is equivalent, but using `char surname[4] = "Woz"` will create a rigid size array, while `char * surname = "Woz"` can be used dynamically.

Comment: A `char*` is something that points to a sequence of chars in the memory, while a `char name[]` is the sequence itself.

Comment: i know that if you want to create, an array, that store strings with different size you need to use `malloc();`, `realloc();` and in the end `free();`, with the pointer `char *surname;`, but i find, that works another way to change the array size  `char* surname="robert"; surname="robertrobertrobert";` works also and array (i suppose) also dynamic, like when we using a `malloc(); realloc(); free();` or no?

Comment: Yes. But with `char * name = "robert";`, the automatic memory allocation is used, while with malloc family the user allocated memory is used. Don't mix the two things; if you used malloc first, and then you want to assign the pointer to a string literal, use free first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, no clear. Do You know some books about automatic memory allocation, or maybe links for more detailed explanation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: I think that the answer to this question is well explained

Comment: Thanks a lot, deeply understand, so my conclusion in the end, if You need in a structure to store char string, that can have different size, the best way - use automatic memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `char name[]` in a struct, your compiler don't know the size of the char tab.
That's why you have to use a pointer in your struct type, or you could use

`char name[MAX_SIZE];` in your struct type.

But I recommand using pointers :)

Comment: But pointer its only a variable, that stored memory address, vs worker.surname stored array, that have a some quantity of char elements, when is reserved memory for string? In this moment: `worker.surname = "Woz";`?

Comment: array name is a pointer, that store address of first array element, or no?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question.

1. Header file quotes. `< >` instead of `" "`
2. I don't think that , C allows the Array declaring like Java do.
   char `name[] = " ";` instead of `char []name=" ";`

   `*name` is simply a pointer.