# Inside-function memory limit in C++

Tags: c++, memory

When i run this code, it breaks

```
main(){
   long a[1000][1000];
}
```

but when i change to this,

```
long a[1000][1000];
main(){}
```

it runs well.

I assumed that there is the memory limit inside-function variables, am i right ?

If so, what is the memory limit (in bytes) for those ?

Comment: Stacks has a limit on its size, and depends on OS and compiler. Thats why your first snippet broke

Comment: Useful reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration. Particularly the piece on Automatic Storage Location (Also Known As most "inside-function variables").

Answer (score 1):

The exact limit is compiler and platform specific.

The difference is in the two snippets is that the first example allocates memory from the [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/10396), while the second allocates it [statically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8385322/10396) - before the program starts.  The stack generally is smaller.