# how primitive type declarations work in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not a C programmer so please be understanding ;)

C language has pointers and all of its goodness. But how a primitive type declaration works?

For example I can do:

`char x = 'a';`

There are no pointers there but the value must be stored somewhere in memory, right? Can I think of above statement as translated to:

```
char* _x = malloc(sizeof(char));
char x = *_x;
```

Comment: In that case, where is `_x` stored?

Comment: Not, not at all. What makes you think so?

Comment: @Broman hmm... nowhere? at execution they are replaced with the memory address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)

Comment: Well, in this case the compiler might optimize it, but that's a completely different story. `x` will be a `char` variable. `_x` will be a pointer variable.

Comment: By your explanation, the value of that pointer must also be stored somewhere in memory too, right? So wouldn't that _actually_ be `char** __x = malloc(sizeof(char*)); ...` /s

Comment: @PatrickRoberts so what happens when I reference a variable that its value is stored in the stack? Do I get a memory location that's on the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't .

```
malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Will allocate memory in the heap, which you're in charge of deleting it . One of the benifits of this, is that the data in allocated memory won't "die" when his scope ends, it will only die when you destruct it .

```
char c = 'a'
```

Will be stored in the stack , and will automatically be released when its scope ends.

**EDIT:** Regarding your comment, in general , local variables will usually be stored in the stack(this is ofcourse , automatic) .  `malloc , calloc` allows you to "ask" for space in the heap, and use it as you wish . If you want more info, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8385322/5353753) , as mentioned by @Jabberwocky

Comment: so the primitive values are kept in the stack because they have small size, yes?

Comment: @marzelin no, the size is totally unrelated. All local variables are allocated on the stack (at least more or lless). You'd best start reading a C text book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wish I had time for that ;)

Comment: @marzelin the duplicate mentioned in your question's comment contains the info you need.

Comment: variable will die, but allocated memory will stay

Comment: oh cool, values on the stack are automatically cleared but I have to take care to clear values stored on the heap. That's one of the differences between a stack and heap. In high-level languages all values are garbage collected automatically (so there's not much difference between the two). That's what I've been missing. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.. Yes , high level languages have their benefits .. but that is because someone wrote you the code that does this automatically. Low level languages have their benefits as well .

Comment: One of the benefits is that they don't hide tricky details behind abstractions. Those details are sometimes very important and quite interesting ;)

Comment: Note that the C language definition says *nothing* about stacks or heaps - it only specifies *behavior* of different types of variables.  It turns out that the best way to implement the behavior of `auto` variables is to use a stack, but that's not *mandatory*.

Comment: @JohnBode: The best way is *generally* to use a stack, but in some cases other approaches may work better.  Using a stack, for example, would require that a system pre-allocate enough contiguous address space to accommodate worst-case stack usage.  An implementation that kept a linked list of storage blocks allocated via some other mechanism could avoid having to assign the stack address space that would never actually get used.

Answer (score 2):

> There are no pointers there but the value must be stored somewhere in memory, right?

In that particular case (`char x = 'a';`) it is likely that the value would practically be stored only inside a processor register. But the program behave ["as-if"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) `x` was in some memory location.

In practice, read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and look into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site. If you want to understand more precisely the (tricky) [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of C11, refer to its standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and look into the [Compcert](http://compcert.inria.fr/) project and into static source code analyzers like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/).
[Memory semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_semantics_(computing)) of C is tricky.

Read also about [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), their [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)), and the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Read also about [storage class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) specifiers (`auto` is the default storage duration). Take time to understand what is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of it.

PS. Your imaginary code lacks some `free(_x)` and that is really important and you should ask yourself where is that `_x` stored! But don't expect us to teach you C (an entire book is needed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I know that `_x` like any other identifier has its value stored in the stack. Pointers are for the heap (generally).

Comment: Pointers are not necessarily in the heap, depends where you point them (the address of the pointer it self is too stored in the stack. Consider : ‘int x = 1; int * y =  &x;’ y will be stored in the stack and as well will point to memory in the stack @marzelin

Comment: Indeed, but the OP used `malloc`

Comment: so there's an internal mapping mechanism that pairs identifiers with memory addresses. When compiler sees `x` it provides its value to be done something with in the instruction. But I can also get the memory address of that identifier with `&x`. Those are automatic mappings, but I can have manual mappings that I control thanks to pointers. Wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

Here

`char x = 'a';`

*There are no pointers there but the value must be stored somewhere in memory, right?* Yes there are no pointers but `x` is local variable and it's stored in `stack` section of primary memory i.e `x` does have valid memory.

> Can I think of above statement as translated to:    char* _x =
>   malloc(sizeof(char));
>
> char x = *_x;

No you can't as `x` here is allocated in `heap` section. So you can't think both scenario as same. And what `*_x` holds ? Garbage. You need to add one more statement after allocating memory

`*_x = 'a';`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't care.

What you need to know is that

```
char x = 'a';
```

declares `x` as a `char` type with *automatic storage duration* and sets the `int` constant `'a'` to it, the value of which depends on the *encoding* your platform uses, but must not overflow a `char`.

Whether or not that survives compilation is another matter entirely. Perhaps your compiler substitutes the number `'a'` whenever you write `x` in your source code; particularly if `x` never changes?

Comment: You're right that I don't need to know that to write code but I'm more interested in knowing how the 'magic' behind translating code into something that computer understands works.

Comment: @marzelin: But you're up a gum tree if you're expecting every variable to be compiled in. Do study the *As-if rule* for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple question with a very complicated answer.

Actually, you're asking two different questions - how storage is allocated for a variable, and how the variable's name is associated with that storage.

As for the first question, the [C language definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) doesn't specify the mechanics of *how* storage for variables is actually allocated - that depends on the compiler, [executable file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats), and operating system. You'll hear people talk about "stack" and "heap", but there's nothing in the C language definition that *mandates* the use of a stack or a heap to manage variables and other objects.

As to the second question, the answer (usually) is, "it isn't."  Variable names are not preserved in the generated machine code.  Instead, the machine code will usually refer to that object via an offset from some address stored in a register.

Comment: does it store information about the type of a variable in the compiled code or if the types are relevant only while compiling? And since I can dereference any variable like: `int a = 1; int* b = &a;` it means that at that memory location for `a` (offset from some address) isn't the value of `a` directly but the address where `1` is. Right?

Comment: @marzelin: Types are only relevant during compilation.  No metadata (size, type, name, etc.) is required to be stored with the variable in the machine code, although compilers may do so for debugging purposes.