# Destructor calling

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, object

I am new into C++ and I am currently learning it. 
While I was exploring web and problems I came across on next code:

```
class A
{
    public:
    ~A() { cout << "A"; }

};

class B
{
    public:
        ~B() { cout << "B"; }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    return 0;
}
```

Output of looks like this:

> BA

Can somebody explains why output looks like this?

Comment: What do you not understand about the output?

Comment: Why isn't it AB? Why there is output at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cleaning up the myth in other answers: no, cleanup order has nothing to do with a stack.

The C++ standard does not even define the concept of a stack except in two circumstances:

- stack unwinding (as a process).
- the stack container adapter.

Neither is relevant here. What **is** relevant though is section 6.6:

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic
>   storage duration that have been constructed in that scope are
>   destroyed **in the reverse order of their construction**.
>
> Transfer out of a loop, out of a block, or back past an initialized
>   variable with automatic storage duration involves the destruction of
>   objects with automatic storage duration that are in scope at the point
>   transferred from but not at the point transferred to.

The fact most architectures implement this behavior using an execution stack is a “happy coincidence”, but it is not mandated by the standard.

On the other hand reverse order destruction **is** guaranteed, regardless of whether the implementation will use a stack or not.

Comment: even more, even on implementation where the stack is used - it is used for function call stacking, it has nothing to do with lifetime within a scope. Maybe for nested scopes.

Comment: Indeed, in fact in the example in OP's question, most likely if optimizations are enabled the stack isn't touched at all within `main`. Perhaps for calling into the c++ runtime…

Comment: That's what I thought so but couldn't find that info. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Objects are destroyed in the reverse order of their creation.

Comment: simple and elegant explanation. A bit lacking, but .. ok

Comment: I must say I flaged it duplicate with the link, but for some reason, it does not appear anymore

Answer (score 0):

The objects in a function are allocated memory in a  heap if they are created using the new keyword.[Dynamic Memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

The objects in a function are allocated memory in a stack (although c++ doesn't mandate that a stack is used) if they are not created using the new keyword.

```
int main( )
{
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

In the above case B is on top of A. Hence it is destroyed first once the function ends. We call destructor to destroy the memory allocation.
[more](https://dzone.com/articles/stack-vs-heap-understanding-java-memory-allocation)

Additional resource: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)