# C Dereferencing pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory

i started to learn C, and i dont know why the app keeps crashing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
}person;

void initPerson(person *aPerson, char name[50], int age)
{
    strcpy(aPerson->name, name); // <- causes a crash
    aPerson->age = age; // <- causes a crash
    printf("%s", aPerson->name);
}

int main()
{
    person *myPerson;
    initPerson(myPerson, "Oscar", 45);

    printf("%s, %i", myPerson->name, myPerson->age);
    return 0;
}
```

I have marked the lines that are causing the crash. Can someone tell me whats the problem?

Comment: `person *myPerson;` You need to allocate memory to `myPerson`.

Comment: You do that with `person *myPerson = malloc(sizeof(person));`.

Comment: Remember, in C you *can* allocate dynamically, but you are not *obliged*: `person myPerson; initPerson(&myPerson, "Oscar", 45);` will work and avoid the layer of complexity associated with dynamic memory management. Google `memory leaks` :)

Comment: Ah, so person myPerson allocates memory automatically, but person *myPerson doesn't, therefore one has to do it manually: person *myPerson = malloc(sizeof(person));

Comment: That's indeed what's meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"...the app keeps crashing., ...Can someone tell me whats the problem?"*
Yes, your program is attempting to write to a memory location it does not own.

If you must use a pointer to `person`, create some memory before using it:

```
int main()
{
    person *myPerson = calloc(1, sizeof(*myPerson));
    if(!myPerson) return 0; //test if failed

    initPerson(myPerson, "Oscar", 45);

    printf("%s, %i", myPerson->name, myPerson->age);
    free(myPerson);//free memory
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can simply pass the *address of* a non-pointer instance of `person` (using `&`) to get the same results:

```
int main()
{
    person myPerson = {0};

    initPerson(&myPerson, "Oscar", 45);
    printf("%s, %i", myPerson.name, myPerson.age);
    return 0;
}
```

The statement:

```
person *myPerson;
```

Creates only an uninitialized pointer, not pointing to any particular place in memory at the time of creation.  The only space used at this point is for the pointer itself, `sizeof(person *)`. (either 4 or 8 bytes for 32bit or 64 bit target respectively.) Before a pointer variable can be used in this way, space must be *dynamically* allocated by a call to _[void *calloc(size_t nitems, size_t size)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)_ or family.  Memory created in this fashion sets the address of the pointer to a memory location coincident  with the first byte of a contiguous block of `nitems*size` bytes set aside and dedicated for use with, in this case, `myPerson`.  Memory allocated in this fashion is referred to as *heap memory* and must be explicitly freed with a call to *[free()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm)* when it is no longer needed.  Generally, this method is recommended only when memory requirements for a particular variable are not known at compile time

But the statement:

```
person myPerson;
```

*Statically* (Or *automatically*, depending on when/where it is created.) allocates memory with `sizeof(person)` bytes for an immediately usable instance of `myPerson`, located in memory at the address: `&myPerson`.  Memory created in this fashion is referred to as *stack memory*. Because passing the address of `myPerson` ( `&myPerson` ) as an argument to `initPerson()`,  and accomplish the same thing as was accomplished with dynamically allocated memory (discussed above), this is a much simpler option as it does not require any memory creation or freeing.

*[Stack and heap memory explained.](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)*

*[Discussion on automatic, static and dynamic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)*