# C multiplying large numbers

Tags: c, memory

The following C program multiplies large numbers as strings. It work works well with positive numbers, but with large numbers too much memory is used. How can I improve it to use less memory?

My program:

```
char *strrev(char *str) {
        char *p1, *p2;

        if(!str || !*str)
            return str;

        for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2) {
            *p1 ^= *p2;
            *p2 ^= *p1;
            *p1 ^= *p2;
        }
        return str;
    }

    char* addNumbers(char* c1, char* c2) {

        char *m1;
        char *m2;


        if (strlen(c1) >= strlen(c2)) {
            m1 = malloc(sizeof(c1));
            m2 = malloc(sizeof(c2));
            strcpy(m1, c1);
            strcpy(m2, c2);
        } else {
            m1 = malloc(sizeof(c2));
            m2 = malloc(sizeof(c1));
            strcpy(m1, c2);
            strcpy(m2, c1);
        }

        strrev(m1);
        strrev(m2);

        int lm1 = strlen(m1);
        int lm2 = strlen(m2);

        //char *w = malloc(1000000);
        char its;
        int jd = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < lm1; l++) {
            int w1 = strToInt(m1[l]);
            int w2;
            if (l < strlen(m2)) {
                w2 = strToInt(m2[l]);
            } else {
                w2 = 0;
            }
            int w3 = w1 + w2 + jd;
            if (w3 > 9) {
                jd = 1;
                w3 = w3 % 10;
            } else {
                jd = 0;
            }
            its = w3 + 48;
            m1[l] = its;
        }
        if (jd > 0) {
            char its2[12];
            sprintf(its2, "%d", jd);
            strcat(m1, its2);
        }

        return strrev(m1);
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        char *c1;
        char *c2;
        if (strlen(argv[1]) > strlen(argv[2])) {
            c1 = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));
            c2 = malloc(sizeof(argv[2]));
            strcpy(c1, argv[1]);
            strcpy(c2, argv[2]);
        } else {
            c1 = malloc(sizeof(argv[2]));
            c2 = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));
            strcpy(c1, argv[2]);
            strcpy(c2, argv[1]);
        }
        char counter[sizeof(c2)];
        sprintf(counter, "%d", 0);
        char one[2];
        sprintf(one, "%d", 1);
        char *w = malloc(100);
        while (strcmp(counter, c2) != 0) {
            strcpy(counter, addNumbers(counter, one));
            strcpy(w, addNumbers(w, c1));
        }
        printf("%s\n%s\n", c1, c2);
        free(c1);
        free(c2);
        printf("Result: %s,%ld\n\n", w,sizeof(w));
        free(w);
    }
```

I know that better algorithms exist, but I am required to use `addNumbers()` function.

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: `sizeof pointer_char` ==> `strlen(pointer_char) + 1`; you have several to change

Comment: At least one big problem: `sizeof(c1)` is not the length of the string. Use `strlen`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: You could have a look at the GMP (The GNU Multiprecision Library). https://gmplib.org// 
That stores large integers as binary which which is (a) considerably more compact and (b) MUCH faster for calculations,

Comment: BTW using XOR for swapping values is discourages nowadays. Use a temoprary variable.

Comment: _but I have to use adding function..._  Do you have to use adding function the way it is, or can it be changed?

Comment: ryyker - function can be changed.

Comment: _malloc()_ is being overused everywhere here. And you are not freeing everything. Simplify your code by static or automatic variables.

Comment: The code you posted is missing a definition for `strToInt()`

Comment: Will you please provide example of inputs?

Comment: Example of inputs are any positive numbers, for example "100 100". strToInt returns argument n - 48

Comment: Are you interested only in having something working even using external libraries or do you want to implement yourself?

Comment: No want to limit external libraries to minimum. Preferably none

Comment: Why do you have to use the add function?

Answer (score 4):

*How can I improve it to save memory?*
As written, your post includes several instances of calls to `calloc()`, each creating heap memory, but none of the memory created is being freed, resulting in memory leaks.  At a very minimum then the answer to your question is to simply make a corresponding call to `free()` for each and every call to `malloc()`.

By the way, there are good discussions on when, where and how to use dynamically allocated memory *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217525/why-or-when-do-you-need-to-dynamically-allocate-memory-in-c)* and *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852762/c-dereferencing-pointer/53852852#53852852)*.

The following is a simplification of the `addNumbers` function, while preserving its original prototype.   As requested in the comments, it uses ANSI C with no additional libraries.   It also features among other things integrated string reversing (Eliminating the `strrev()` function), uses only one instance of dynamically allocated memory, and leaks none.

Note, the example uses hard coded inputs for illustration, but by uncommenting the `scanf()` functions, and adding command line inputs, it can easily be converted to match your needs.

```
char* addNumbers(char* s1, char* s2) ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s1[101] = {"150353265326"};
    char s2[101] = {"22055653351"};

    // Expect: 3316139500221184007426

    //scanf(" %s",s1);
    //scanf(" %s",s2);
    char * result = addNumbers(s1, s2); 


    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}


char* addNumbers(char* s1, char* s2) 
{
    int i=0, j=0, tmp;

    int l1 = strlen(s1);
    int l2 = strlen(s2);
    int a[100]={0},b[100]={0};
    int ans[200] = {0};
    char *result = calloc(l1+l2+1, 1);

    for(i = l1-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)
    {
        a[j] = s1[i]-'0';
    }
    for(i = l2-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)
    {
        b[j] = s2[i]-'0';
    }
    for(i = 0;i < l2;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < l1;j++)
        {
            ans[i+j] += b[i]*a[j];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < l1+l2;i++)
    {
        tmp = ans[i]/10;
        ans[i] = ans[i]%10;
        ans[i+1] = ans[i+1] + tmp;
    }
    for(i = l1+l2; i>= 0;i--)
    {
        if(ans[i] > 0)
            break;
    }

    for(j=i;j >= 0;j--)
    {
        result[i-j] = (char)('0' + ans[j]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Tested using command line inputs:

[image]

Note: This adaptation gives credit to *[this implementation.](https://awsmcode.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/multiplying-large-numbers-in-cc/)*

Answer (score 1):

You are using up lots of memory by allocating it but not freeing it. Even if you do free it, you have lots of allocation, copying and deallocation.

Rather than doing that, you would be better allocating space for the result, then accumulating in the same result until your product is finished.

As your inputs can be const strings, you should aim for only one malloc in your main() function to allocate the space for the result, then the rest is modifying that in-place. If you need to reverse the input strings, then you will need a couple more allocations, but that's all. I would not do the addition in strings, but use an array of uint_8 and do the strToInt conversion once for each input at the start rather than many, many times in the loop.