# Doesn't work function free and code always crashed

Tags: c

My code crash coz free() doesn't want to clear array. First of all i create array and add to there a numbers. After that i enter K (k < m) and creates new matrix MxK. k - amount of number of first array in line. And if the number are over , should fill in the rest matrix with zeros. I use while for reuse, but my code crash when i use big array and big matrix. With what it can be connected?

```
`int main() {
    while(1){
    int m,k;
    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    int res;
    do
    {
        res=scanf("%d",&m);
        if(res!=1)printf("it should be a number!");

    }
    while(res!=1);

    int * a = (int*) malloc(m*sizeof(int)); 


    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
            do
            {
            res=scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            flush();
            if(res!=1) printf("it should be a number!\n");
            }
            while(res!=1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    printf("\nEnter K: ");
    do
    {
    res=scanf("%d",&k);
    flush();
    if(res!=1 || k>m) printf("k<m must be or enter number\n");
    }
    while(res!=1 || k>m);

    int all=k*m;
    for(i=m;i<all;i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
    int j;
    int n=0;
    int s[i][j];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
    s[i][j] = a[n];
    printf("%d ",s[i][j]);
    n++;
    }
    printf( "\n" );
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        free(s[i][j]);
    }
    }   
int povtor;   ----- exit using break
char temp[10];
printf("Continue?(1 - No, everything - Yes): ");
gets(temp);
povtor = atoi(temp);
if (povtor == 1 ) break; 

}
return 0;
}`
```

Comment: `int j;` followed by `int s[i][j];`... What is the value of `j` at that point? I suggest you learn how to use [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a lot of problems.

First, you can only `free` something that was allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.  This doesn’t apply to `s[i][j]`.

But that’s only one issue.  You allocate `a` to hold `m` elements:

```
int * a = (int*) malloc(m*sizeof(int));
```

but then you try to write past the end of the array here:

```
int all=k*m;
for(i=m;i<all;i++)
{
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

You need to resize `a` before attempting that, otherwise you are writing over memory you don’t own:

```
int *tmp = realloc(a, sizeof *a * all );
if ( !tmp )
{
  // resize failed, exit with error
}
a = tmp;
for( i = m; i < all; i++ )
{
  a[i] = 0;
}
```

Then there’s this:

```
int j;
int n=0;
int s[i][j];
```

What is the value of `j` at this point?  For that matter, what is the value of `i`?  Are you sure you don’t mean `s[m][k]`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to free an int, and not a pointer : `int s[i][j]` is an array of array of `int`, hence `s[][]` is a int.

Even though, s is automatic memory allocated : basically, its a variable stored in the *stack* so you don't need to free it. Trying to free static variable results in crash. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation) may help you.

By the way, you have a lot of uninitialized variable, resulting in conditionals jumps and possible crashs : for example, you declare `int j` without a value and after you use it to declare your array of array.

Finally, don't use gets. This function is dangerous, use fgets instead. I suggest you read the manual page of gets to understand why.