# Allocate memory to a specific "string"

Tags: c

I just started to learn [memory management](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation) in C, and I didn't understand something. I want to allocate memory to a buffer that holds 12 bytes. which is the exact size of `Hello World!` without null terminator.

Then I want to append a string to the current string with `strcat`, and of course I cannot do that because I will get `core dumped` error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char mystr[12] = "Hello World!";
    # allocate memory to mystr?
    char *ptr = (char*) malloc(13 * sizeof(char));
    
    strcat(mystr, "Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

So, I don't know how can I allocate memory to the `mystr` variable if `malloc` doesn't take any other arguments except the target size.

Comment: 12 bytes. which is the exact size of `"Hello World!"`.That is exactly 1 byte too short to hold `"Hello World!"`

Comment: You should read the manual and check, what `strcat` does. Where do you expect the extra 5 bytes to go if the array already holds maximum number of char?

Comment: You cannot resize `mystr` after statically allocating it

Comment: @Gerhardh So this is want I want to do, add another 5 bytes to the buffer and then I will be able to `strcat` another string.

Comment: As Inian commented, you cannot modify the size of an array after its definition.

Comment: @Gerhardh Really? So I clearly didn't understand nothing memory management (`malloc`, etc.)

Comment: `mystr` is not related at all to dynamic memory management. You don't use `malloc` etc. on `mystr`.

Comment: @ArlichBachman: You should consider going through - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8385322/5291015

Comment: Rolled back to the original question, so that comments make sense.

Comment: @Gerhardh it is exactly the *right* size to hold "Hello World!" but no null terminator is supplied.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, for the comments. Hmm...

Comment: @Acorn well you know that SO isn't a moving tutorial session, with a question like shifting sand.

Comment: @WeatherVane Agreed, it is always confusing when that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know how can I allocate memory to the `mystr` variable if `malloc` doesn't take any other arguments except the target size.

It is not possible to allocate extra memory to an array. Instead, what you want to do is allocate a new block of memory, copying the original string into the beginning of that memory (`strcpy`), then append the rest (`strcat`):

```
char *p = (char*) malloc((12 + 5 + 1) * sizeof(char));

strcpy(p, myptr);
strcat(p, "Hello");
```

12 for the first string, plus 5 for the second, plus one for the null-terminator.

Of course, since you know the final size, you could also simply allocate a big enough array instead of using `malloc` (and you can also use `memcpy`, too).

Comment: what if you do not know how much to allocate?

Comment: you do not "allocate" large enough array only define it.

Comment: @P__J__ Answers should not try to replace C books by covering every single possible case.

Comment: @P__J__ It is a stack allocation, though. Yes, in legalese we wouldn't call it that way.

Comment: But should answer the question. This one does not.  You could also say declare it char `*mystr[4*1024*1024]` and this string will be enough to keep 1200pages book

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that a string in C *always* end with a NULL character (also noted `'\0'`), so your string is actually *13* characters long. (That character is always automatically added with string literals and serves at telling where the string stops, because a string doesn't have a fixed length.)

So the `strcat` tries to read the string `Hello world!` followed by garbage (since the null-terminator is not included in the string).

P.S.: the error is not the `core dumped` but the `Segmentation fault` that precedes it, and this tells you that you are trying to change something in a segment you are not supposed to change (or execute/read something you are not supposed to -- this is a security feature).

Edit: after modifying the string `mystr`, you also need to change the length you allocate (in the `malloc`: use `13 * sizeof(char)`, or more simply here in this case `sizeof(mystr)`).

P.S. 2: also comments in C are started by `//`, not `#` (those are preprocessor directives).

Comment: The main problem wasn't with the buffer size of the string. It was that I didn't know **that I can't change the buffer size of a string** that I already declared. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: That is not entirely true. The original question defined `char mystr[12] = "Hello World!";` which stores the 12 characters but no null terminator. This is quite legal except the array is not a "string".

Answer (score 0):

you cant change the size of the array. `mystr` has to be also dynamically allocated.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    const char *ptr = "Hello World!";
    const char *ptr2 = "hello";
    char *mystr = malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);

    strcpy(mystr, ptr);
    mystr = realloc(mystr, strlen(mystr) + strlen(ptr2) + 1);
    strcat(mystr, ptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Gerhardh it is also no good to do no check result if `malloc`.  But this time intentionally I have sacrificed the correctness.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for letting me know! I will be fine, thanks fam. Before that I need to learn first what `const` is (';